# sql query to select a random row from a table based on the previous query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am writing a simple letter guess game where the categories and phrases are stored in a sqlite database.
One table (categories) holds the table name and the human readable title of the table.
There are 31 other tables with the phrases in them.

while i can do this with two sql queries, first to retrieve a random table name, and another to retrieve the random phrase from the second table.

```
"SELECT tablename, title FROM categories order by Random() limit 1";
```

then assign tablename to the variable table.

```
"SELECT phrase FROM " + table + " order by Random() limit 1";
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to combine these statements so that i can store it as a view and then my program doesn't need to know about the internal structure of the database.

I hope i have explained this clearly enough, thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend fixing your design. These 31 tables should be just one table, with the category being a column.

Comment: I really thought about that, however there are approximately 50,000 phrases in this database, I'm not sure how to automate that procedure. the source code is in a github repo at https://github.com/bcburnett/TodoList

Comment: I'd be inclined to try creating a view that UNION ALLs those 31 tables (assuming they have a similar structure). Then presumably you can apply the Random() select to the view without having to be concerned with a table name. I don't think it's possible to "dynamically" choose a table to query using a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this is not possible on a database that doesn't support stored procedures like sqlite unfortunately.